# how to make a secure client/server connection over websocket in nodejs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ssl, websocket

You probably think this question can be marked as a duplicate, but I searched everywhere and didn't find what I'm looking for.

I'm developing an ionic-react app and using a nodejs server as backend. I'm connecting my client to the server over websocket. I'm using the [socketIO-client library](https://socket.io/) in the client side and the https built in module and the express framework for the server side.

Everything works fine when I'm using **http** or **ws** connection. Now my app is ready for production and I'm switching to https or wss in my case because I want to use websocket. I'm doing this for the first time so this is very confusing to me.

Here is my client code (I changed secure to true since I read that I should do that if I'm planning to use https/ ssl):

```
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = socketIOClient("wss://localhost:8000", { secure: true });
```

Here is my server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var ws = require('ws').Server;
// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem').toString(),

};

var app = express();
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);

var wss = new ws({
    server: httpsServer
});


wss.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("client connected");

    socket.on("message", (msg) => {
        console.log("received: ", msg);
    });

    socket.on("disconnection", () => {
        console.log("client disconnected");
    })
});
httpsServer.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("server running on 8000");
})
```

I generated the ssl certificate by following [this example](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/).
My code works perfectly when I'm using http but suddenly I get an error when using https/wss although I added the ssl certificate.

Interestingly, the error I get in chrome is different from the error in firefox. Here is error I get in chrome (it even looks like two independent errors):

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NFuRgsF' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
    polling-xhr.js:268 

GET https://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NFuRgsF net::ERR_FAILED
```

Here is the error I get in firefox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NFuR-Im. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

I tried and disable all my borwser plugins (e.g adblock) but it didn't work. I further tried to set up the header and configure cors ( I found this on the internet while reading about the cors error):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    
    next();
  });
```

However, adding this code didn't change nothing and the error still appears. I don't know what should I do about this. Maybe it is a stupid question but do I need to provide the certificate also in the client side somehow? is this a client or server side issue?

Comment: Did you also trust the self-signed certificate you generated ?

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros I don't think so. Sorry I'm really new to this. I don't even know how to trust it or what does it mean in the context

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros So I read about the trusting thing on the internet. It turns out that i need that only in production, but in my case here I'm trying this on localhost and it's not even working. correct?

Comment: It depends on how you signed the certificate.

Comment: Does the https website work for you ?

Comment: @AntoineRaoulIscaros I didn't signed nothing actually. I just followed this simple steps from the nodejs website https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/